# Extract continuous information from telnet client

Tags: telnet

I have an industrial sensor that via an Interface module provides raw values via `telnet`.

In order to connect to it:

```
  telnet 169.254.168.150 10001
```

I can only see garbage values from it.

### Information

The information that I have is from the datasheet of the Interface module.

The sensor is an analog one, hence `Status` flag is not relevant.

[image: Data format]

I have some propreitary software from the company which visualizes the information of the sensor. This software also uses the above mentioned telnet protocol to obtain information. I cross checked it via WireShark. Packet size is 22 Bytes and in little-endian.

[image: Wireshark Dump]

I cannot programatically obtain the information as my [SE Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53432812/unable-to-unpack-information-between-custom-preamble-in-python-and-telnetlib) and I am looking to obtain the value maybe store the incoming values directly somewhere (in DB or file).

Is there any way to extract this infomation via the Command Line?

Comment: The datasheet describes a format which has a lot longer than 22 bytes, so either you need to look at several packets, or the datasheet doesn't match the telnet format. Also note the `MEAS` field, which is nowhere to be seen. First thing I'd do is `telnet 169.254.168.150 10001 | hexdump C` (assuming Unixoid OS) and look at *a lot* more data instead of a single packet.

Comment: A simple Perl script could easily read and decode/unpack the data

Comment: @waltinator never used `perl` before. Mind guiding me to some blogs which can achieve the goal?

Comment: @dirkt I have the output pasted for the command you mentioned. here is the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fn4pdaxP), I can read the preamble however the I do not get any other information from the dump

Comment: Blogs won't do it. Buy the "Programming Perl" book (by Larry Wall, published by O'Reilly & Co.).  Or, write it in C. Bash is not suited to binary data manipulation.

Comment: never mind found out the solution using python and sockets

Comment: You pasted the dump of the data, formatted by `hexdump -c`. Find the "MEAS" string, and look at the following bytes.

Comment: I created a `tcp` client to call the 10001 port and then when ahead and did as you mentioned. Unfortunately, there are 2 x 22 Bytes data coming in. 1st is the preamble information and then the data values. I will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Extract from the pastebin:

```
00000050  2e 0a 53 41 45 4d 00 00  00 00 f6 04 00 00 15 00  |..SAEM..........|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 0c 00 01 00 fa 94  |................|
00000070  00 00 8c 00 00 00 8c 00  00 00 0a 23 00 00 53 41  |...........#..SA|
00000080  45 4d 00 00 00 00 f6 04  00 00 15 00 00 00 00 00  |EM..............|
```

So this shows the information is all there, it's little endian, and you just have to read and parse them. Any tool you are confortable with will do; a C program, a `perl` program, anything you like. You may have to skip over the `telnet` output at the beginning, or use something else instead of `telnet` (e.g. `nc`, `netcat`, `socat`).

To demonstrate `perl`, to decode one packet, you'd do something like

```
cat ... | perl -nle "print join(':',unpack 'a4 (L2 Q L S2 l4)<')"
```

on the command line for the packet in the dump, and get as output

```
SAEM:0:1270:21:0:12:1:38138:140:140
```

This only works for the given number of channels (and the mask says that one of the four measurement values shouldn't be present, but it has a value; I don't understand that part).

If you get a variable number of channels depending on other information, you need smarter parsing.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I thought the other way round. Since I was capturing data on Wireshark all the packets were `tcp` and only the initial few packets were of `telnet` (session initiation information).

I decided to create a `tcp` socket using python and read the data of 22 bytes (size available from Wireshark Dump)

and I used `struct` module to `unpack` the information. Interesting was to find out that the useful sensor information came always as the alternate TCP payload i.e. First packet had only information like *preamble*, *article number*, *serial number* etc. and the next payload had all the information `Counter`, *Channel 1 value*, *Channel 2 value*, *Channel 3 value*

The information obtained here was in `int32` which needs to converted to appropriate value using a formula mentioned in the module's instruction manual

### Code

```
import socket
import struct

# CONSTANTS for Formula
# ....

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('169.254.168.150', 10001)
print('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.connect(server_address)


def value_mm(raw_val):
""" Formula for conversion """
    return (((raw_val - DRANGEMIN) * MEASRANGE) / (DRANGEMAX - DRANGEMIN) + OFFSET)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        Laser_Value = 0
        data = sock.recv(22)
        # First frame
        preamble, article, serial, x1, x2 = struct.unpack('<4sIIQH', data)

        # if this payload is not the preamble, it must be information payload
        if not preamble == b'SAEM':
            status, bpf, mValCounter, CH1, CH2, CH3 = struct.unpack('<hIIIII',data)
            #print(CH1, CH2, CH3)
            Laser_Value = CH3
            print(str(value_mm(Laser_Value)) + " mm")

        print('\n')
```